# Riemann-Zeta Function at non-integer points

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, riemann-zeta

I was wondering if there is a technique for evaluating the Riemann-zeta function at non-integer points please.

I am aware of the technique from complex analysis that when $s \in \mathbb{N}$, we can construct a function such as

\begin{equation*}
f(z) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\pi \cot(\pi z)}{z^s} & \quad s \text{ is even} \\[1ex]
\frac{\pi \sec(\pi z)}{z^s} & \quad s \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

And consider the contour integral and Cauchy's residue theorem to deduce the value of $\zeta(s)$.

However, the above argument relies on the fact that the Laurent series of $f$ around $0$ and $\operatorname{res}(f(z), 0)$ are easy to find (namely, we can recall the Laurent expansion for $\cot(\pi z)$, and the residue is precisely the coefficient of the $(s-1)$th term of which).

I am not sure whether this argument still applies, if we let $s$ to be a non-integer parameter, in this case the Laurent series probably won't be that nice.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by evaluating?

Comment: I'd like to obtain a concrete value or closed form expression for the zeta function @Conrad

Comment: can you do $\zeta(5)?$

Comment: I think a similar argument follows, we can consider $f(z) = \frac{\pi \sec(\pi z)}{z^5}$

Comment: Try and do it and see where you fail; it is quite a famous open problem to learn about zeta at odd integers (the proof that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational hasn't yet been extended except in ways that show that out some odd zetas, most must be irrational but no specific one known for sure except at $3$)

Comment: Aha - thank you! I think by the above method, the series that we obtain is actually the alternating Hurwitz zeta function $\zeta^{*} (5, 0.5) = \displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n - 0.5)^5}$ instead of the Riemann zeta function @Conrad